# behaviorsubject Result of subscribe updated from callback

Tags: typescript, callback, rxjs, angular7, subscribe

I can't figure why or how the values are being updated from the callback, I though the BehaviorSubject could only be updated through next()... but maybe it's the lack of sleep?

Here is the code :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  private testSource = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  testCurrent = this.testSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }
  changeTest(test: any) {
    this.testSource.next(test);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-another',
  template: `<div *ngFor="let nope of whatEver">{{nope.bananas}}</div>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class AnotherComponent {
  @Input() rando: string;
  constructor(private data: DataService) { }
  whatEver: [];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.testCurrent.subscribe(aha => {
      // WORKS FINE:
      const omg = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(aha))
      this.whatEver = omg.reduce((accu, a) => {
      // DOES NOT WORK (changes the variable aha -> WHY?):
      //this.whatEver = aha.reduce((accu, a) => {
        a.bananas = a.bananas.filter(b => b === this.rando || b === "yellow");
        accu.push(a);
        return accu;
      }, []);
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<app-another *ngFor="let why of maybe" [rando]="why"></app-another>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  idontknow = [
    {
      id: "come-on",
      bananas: ["yellow", "big", "tasty"]
    }
  ];
  maybe = ["yellow", "big", "tasty"];
  constructor(private data: DataService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.changeTest(this.idontknow);
  }
}
```

This is the working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdez5o

My issue: as the code is above, it works fine (I have my bananas). However, if you comment out the 2 lines below `WORKS FINE`and uncomment the line below `DOES NOT WORK` then I only have yellow bananas.
Could it be a funny reference to the aha object even in separate instances of the component? How is that possible and what am I missing? Do I have to make a copy of aha for it to work? I'm quite baffled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is because of this line:

```
a.bananas = a.bananas.filter(...);
```

You're reassigning a property of the object that's emitted by the BehaviorSubject. It's emitted three times (once for each app-another that subscribes to it). This means that the second time around, `a.bananas` will be whatever was filtered from the previous subscription.

To resolve this, don't reassign the object property. Create a new object with corresponding properties. For example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tumnrd?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
const bananas = a.bananas.filter(...);
accu.push({ ...a, bananas });
```

You also don't need (or necessarily want) to create a subscription. You will have to unsubscribe (probably in ngOnDestroy) or there's a potential for memory leaks. I suggest using the async pipe to handle this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tumnrd?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
this.whatEver = this.data.testCurrent.pipe(
  map(aha =>
    aha.map(({ bananas }) => ({
      bananas: bananas.filter(b => b === this.rando || b === 'yellow')
    }))
  )
);
// ... in template ...
<div *ngFor="let nope of whatEver | async">{{nope.bananas}}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Explosion Pills, before I accept the answer, are you saying it's perfectly normal that the object in the service is updated from within that part of the code? Isn't that not supposed to happen?

Comment: Why do you think it's not supposed to happen? Objects are references, so if you update an object's properties in one place it reflects anywhere that object is used which is part of the purpose of using objects.

Comment: Don't know... :-) thanks that makes sense (I guess). Side note: how do you call this notation: `({ bananas })` ?

Comment: This is destructuring. When you have a single arrow function argument that’s destructured, you have to wrap it in parentheses or it’s a syntax error.